# AngularJS Mongoose error handling

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've build a simple application with AngularJS. Part of this application is calling REST services. For that, I'm using mongoose. Everything works great, but I'd like to better handle errors. A sample code could be :

Express:

```
DBCollection.find({}, function (err, tuples) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error!');
            }
            res.send(JSON.stringify(tuples));
        });
```

AngularJS:

```
DBService.query(function (res) {
            $scope.data.lists = res;   
});
```

The problem I'm faced with is as follow. Imagine I've got an error on the mongodb server side. I've got an error, so I log it in the console and then ? What happens on the angularjs/front-end side ? If I send the error as a http response, I suppose angular would interpreate it as the response of the query but with unexpected content and produce an exception ? how to deal with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular is like Santa, it knows when responses are bad or good.  There are 2 solutions, ones solutions is to create an error handler on each request.  The other is to use `$httpProvider.interceptors` to globally handle errors before they become a problem on an individual request level.

**Option 1**

```
DBService.query(function (res) {
    scope.data.lists = res;   
},function(errorResult){
    console.log(errorResult); // <- take a peek in here, find something useful
});
```

**Option 2**

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q',function($q) {
    return {
        'responseError': function(rejection) {
            console.log(rejection); // <- take a peek in here, find something useful
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: I forgot that underneath $resource, it is $http and the promise has two methods success and error. Furthermore, I'm not familiar with $q and even less with interceptors... so I would adopt option 1. Thanks!